# Google Cloud VM Instance with Wordpress Repeatedly Crashes

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, stackdriver

I've got a newly deployed Google Cloud f1-micro VM Instance using the Google Click to Deploy Wordpress solution. I've done some basic configurations such as a static IP, DNS config, persistent disk, etc. I also imported data from a previous Wordpress install.

The issue is that about every 10-15 minutes the server crashes and becomes unresponsive. Error 500 when trying to view any page, and SSH becomes unreachable. The console shows the VM Instance is still running though. I have to Reset the VM Instance, and then everything is restored within a few seconds. CPU usage is almost always below 50%. The site currently has almost zero traffic, just me testing it.

Any idea what may be causing it to freeze/crash so often? I know the f1-micro is not a powerful server, but I've read a lot about running Wordpress on it and it seems like it should be able to handle a low traffic website.

Comment: F1-micro for WordPress and MySQL is way too small. Wordpress without MySQL is just OK. With MySQL you will see crashes often. Small is the smallest size that I would recommend. Bump up the instance size and verify if I am correct.

Comment: You might want to move this into ServerFault.

Comment: Instance type: e2-micro with 1GB RAM should work which is more modest on cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see system log from console in Web UI

[image: Click Serial port1 (console)]

Or you can use CLI

```
gcloud compute --project={your project id} instances get-serial-port-output {vm name}
```

f1-micro only have 0.2core and 0.60 memory. it can not support both wordpress and mysql. I think it out of memory, and system keep kill your process (mysql or wordpress). I suggestion you upgrade to bigger vm.

Comment: I just opened up the system log, and an SSH console with top running to monitor processes and memory usage. I clicked around the site several times for a few minutes, and it eventually crashed. The whole time the amount of free memory seemed to stay constant within a few MB. The Serial port 1 system log in the console did not log anything new during this time. It appears mysql and apache2 processes are still running. In fact, there are several apache2 processes. Maybe they are not terminating correctly?

Comment: Eventually crashed which means ? The process be killed ? or the vm unresponsive while you still keep your ssh connection ? free memory seemed to stay constant within a few MB is not a good sign. You should upgrade first . Check whether it can survival longer or not.

Comment: This answer was correct. It appeared to have memory, but could not handle even a couple page requests without freezing up. Moving to the next size up worked fine.